# Can players spend Fate points to introduce story details in FAE?

Tags: fate-accelerated, fate-points

In Fate Core, players can pay a Fate point to Declare a story detail based on one of their aspects.

In Fate Accelerated Edition, I found no reference to this. Fate points seem to only add +2 or −2 to a roll.

Are players meant to be able to establish story details in FAE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rules as written: No.

The closest FAE comes is on page 12:

> Your character’s own aspects provide a good guide for what you can do.
>   If you have an aspect that suggests you can perform magic, then cast
>   that spell. If your aspects describe you as a swordsman, draw that
>   blade and have at it. These story details don’t have additional
>   mechanical impact.

Depending on how you interpret that, it either gives the detail granting powers of Fate Core without the cost, or it may be a more limited version of that power.

Via [Fred of Evil Hat's Blog](http://www.deadlyfredly.com/2015/09/fae-q-approach-alts/):

> For the record (again), FAE is Fate Core. It’s got the dials cranked in deliberately different directions than Core’s given defaults

FAE is an example of how to twist the dials in Fate to create a very simple game. Fate is designed to be highly hackable, so you can drop in the version from Fate Core if your table prefers it.